Why can't I read comments on Reddit with emacs-w3m?
Whenever I open a Reddit page in emacs-w3m, I can't see the comments.
Any pointers as to why?;)

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764624/how-can-you-use-javascript-in-terminal-for-w3m

Probably javascript. You could debug the page to be sure.
